Should the date on a provisional degree certificate be used as "Degree Conferral Date" on applications?
So essentially, I haven't received my MA or BA degree certificates/diploma yet. I do have a provisional degree certificate for my BA degree, and the MA convocation is (unofficially) due to happen by the end of this year.
I'm filling out applications for PhD positions in the US (I'm an international applicant) and not sure as to which date should I put in the "Degree Conferred or Expected" section; the one I have on my provisional degree certificate or something else? For my MA I am assuming that I will just put 'December 2024', as the date it is expected.
Would greatly appreciate some input on this.

I am unfamiliar with your system. It sounds like you are in a joint BA/MA program, no? Is your BA provisional because it is awarded at the same time as your BA, or for some other rreason?

If you're applying for PhD positions now in the US, you're likely expecting to start a program in Fall 2025.
It will likely be important for required degrees (like a BS) to be officially awarded before you are able to start. It may be somewhat important for other degrees (like a MS) to be officially awarded before you are able to start. It is very very normal that applicants to US PhD programs will not have their degrees yet. The most typical path for a domestic student would be applying now for Fall 2025 when they expect to complete their bachelor's degree late in Spring 2026, past application deadlines and even past admissions decisions. Other applicants may have masters degrees pending instead, or may have taken time for a research job or even a job outside of academia.
So, it's no problem at all that you do not have your degree yet, if it says "Degree Conferred or Expected" in your case you care about the "Expected" part, because yours hasn't been Conferred (officially awarded) yet. Put whatever date you expect that you will be officially given the degree. Even if you've already completed all your requirements, that's the date they want. It sounds like you know what that date is for your Masters degree, so now you just need to figure out what the likely official date will be for your Bachelors. I don't know how you need to figure that out, but it seems like something between you and the institution giving you that degree. If "provisional" means "we've already given you the degree but the official paperwork is in the mail/post" and once you receive that paperwork it will have the same provisional date, you could possibly use that, but if it were me I would like to have some confirmation from the institution that this is acceptable.
In your CV, you may choose to indicate when you actually completed degree requirements regardless of when the degree is awarded, particularly if you feel that helps to make clear the timeline of your education, but admissions committees in the US will be familiar with concurrent BS/MS degrees that are common in other countries (assuming that describes your situation), even if they are not particularly common in the US.

Hi! So actually, “provisional degree certificate”, in my country, is an actual piece of paper, provided by the institution when asked for by a student, that acts as a sort of proof that indeed the person has graduated, and just hasn’t yet been given the actual degree certificate/diploma yet. It includes the final CGPA and overall result and remarks, with the signature from the Registrar, HOD of the department and other concerned authorities.

You need to be completely honest and even a bit conservative in such things to protect yourself. If you are filling out forms that have room, give the date and mark it as provisional. It is probably still "expected". You don't want to get into a situation where someone asks for verification and it doesn't come.
If the forms don't allow any explanations and are just check boxes and date fields, then put a couple of sentences elsewhere in your application to make it clear.
You might also contact the university, perhaps the "registrar's" office to ask this question. Has the degree officially been awarded? If they agree that it has this becomes much simpler. It isn't your receipt of the diploma that matters, but the date on which the university "acts" to confer the degree. Systems vary, so ask the university.
